# Detect if activity was launched normally or after NFC tag was read (without any prompt)

Tags: java, android, nfc, ndef, android-applicationrecord

If Android Application Record (AAR) is used, intent action is

```
android.intent.action.MAIN
```

So I can not know if this is normal launch or nfc launch.

I need to do slighty different things in my activity whether activity is launched normally or after nfc tag reading. I also dont want to show prompt for choosing app if there is another app on the phone with the same intent filter, e.g.:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

[Edit]:

Check for payload in your intent: [EXTRA_TAG](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#EXTRA_TAG) or [EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NfcAdapter.html#EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)

This extra will always be set if the intent comes from an NFC event.

---

[obsolete]:

> Use
> [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent())
> and check its
> [action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getAction())

Comment: I checked intent and if i use AAR, action is android.intent.action.MAIN, so i can distinguish it from normal launch. How can i detect nfc launch from AAR or by using any other procedure?

Comment: This is good trick, but if there are 2 apps on my phone with intent as in my question, i still have to choose (prompt shown) which app should hande this intent.

Comment: well for second part of your question, read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#aar 
Make sure you only added one AAR record to your NdefMessage using `NdefRecord.createApplicationRecord(..)`

Comment: I added just 1 AAR, but then action is android.intent.action.MAIN. Maybe i dont get your answer, could you please tell a bit more.

Comment: First, to start only your app, the NdefMessage has to have 1 (one) AAR so it knows which app to start. Otherwise you get the prompt shown.
Second, to distinguish between normal start and NFC start, check if `EXTRA_TAG` does exist (e.g. if it's `null` or not) in the intent you're receiving from `getIntent()`.

Otherwise I guess I misread your question.

Comment: Ok now i get it (will accept your answer). One more thing. Is it possible to add any data to AAR?

Comment: Not to the AAR directly since [createApplicationRecord(..)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefRecord.html#createApplicationRecord(java.lang.String)) takes only one argument (packageName) but you can add multiple `NdefRecord`s to an [`NdefMessage`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/NdefMessage.html)

Comment: Ok thanx, i will create NDEF text record (extra data for my app) and AAR record (to only launch my app without prompt).

Comment: When AAR is the first (or only) NDEF record, always an ACTION_MAIN intent will be sent to the app, without any TAG or NDEF_MESSAGES EXTRAs. So it is not true that these EXTRAs will always be set if the intent comes from an NFC event

Answer (score 6):

If you put the AAR *not* as the first record of the NDEF message (so 2nd record or later) and you put an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent filter in the manifest for the first record of the NDEF message, your app will get an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent when launched from a tag. The intent will have EXTRAs containing a handle to the tag and the complete NDEF message.

If the AAR is the first record, an ACTION_MAIN intent will be sent to the app. This intent will not contain any tag or NDEF message in the EXTRAs.

To prevent your app from showing up when scanning other NFC tags, make sure that the first NDEF record has a type that is unique to your app and filter for that. The [External Type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc.html#ext-type) was specifically designed for this purpose. (Due to the AAR in your tag, no other apps will show up when you scan it.)